# How come LAST_ACK doesn't enter CLOSE_WAIT?

Tags: networking, connection, tcp

When a TCP connection is closed at one end of the connection - the other end receives a `FIN` and responds with an `ACK`. This end of the connection then enters the `CLOSE_WAIT` state. Once `close()` is called at this end the TCP sends a `FIN` packet and enters the `LAST_ACK` state. However, it never enters the `TIME_WAIT` state.

[image: The TCP State Transition Diagram]

Now, let's suppose that the Host A calls `close()` on the socket and sends a `FIN` packet to Host B. Host A enters the `FIN_WAIT_1` state. Host B receives the `FIN` packet, sends an `ACK` and then enters the `CLOSE_WAIT` state. However, the ACK is dropped somewhere in an upstream router.

Meanwhile, Host B calls `close()` (recall that Host B is in the `CLOSE_WAIT` state) and sends a `FIN` packet to Host A. Host B now enters the `LAST_ACK` state. Host A receives the `FIN` packet and replies with an `ACK`. It then enters the `CLOSING` state.

At the other end, Host B is still in the `LAST_ACK` state. It then receives the `ACK` from Host A and enters the `CLOSED` state. Recall that the `ACK` from Host B to Host A was dropped and that Host A has not resent it's `FIN` packet. Host A resends it's `FIN` packet on timeout - however Host B has closed the connection.

Is Host A now stuck in the `CLOSING` state? Can the connection teardown continue? What happens next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My TCP's a little rusty but I believe it works like this:

When Host B calls `close()` and sends its `FIN`, the Sequence number on that `FIN` will reveal to Host A that it missed a packet from Host B. So Host A won't Ack Host B's `FIN`, it'll keep Ack'ing the last TCP segment that it successfully received from Host B. This will prompt Host B to retransmit the missing `ACK`.

So Host A won't reach the `CLOSING` state, because it won't consider the out-of-order `FIN` to be truly received until it receives the missing `ACK` that preceded it.